# How to receive data from Custom JSP kept inside ROOT\WEB-INF\classes path

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have modified the static page of the Liferay Page by using portal-ext.properties inside 
D:\Liferay\Liferay Tomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes

### **portal-ext.properties

auth.login.community.url=/Test.jsp**

**This Particular Test.jsp is kept under path 
D:\Liferay\Liferay Tomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\webapps\ROOT**

This is my Test.jsp page

```jsp
<form method="POST" action="/MyActionclass">
    Enter your name:</font><input type="text" name="username" size="20"></p>
    Enter your password:</font><input type="text" name="password" size="20"></p>
</form>
```

This works fine, custom page is loaded.

Please tell me, where to configure this MyActionclass so that it will receive the data submitted from the JSP?

My requirement is that, once the username and password are validated inside the MyActionclass (Hardocded as per now), I will display my portlets developed.

Comment: Well, I would say you are doing it in a very, very strange way :) What do you want to do specifically? Explain your problem so we can present a better solution.

Comment: Upon entering http:localhost:8080 , i would like to display a custom login page , and upon entering credentials , i would like to display my two Portlets .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a custom Portlet using the Liferay 6 Plugins-SDK for your solution. Then you can just use the standard Portlet architecture to handle the authentication etc.

Equally you can just use Liferay's login portlet to authenticate users.

Either way you'll need to set permissions on the portlets you want to display after successful login to not have Guest "View" permissions, and make sure that the Role assigned to Logged in users has "View" permissions. This will hide them from any non Liferay authenticated user.

If you look at the Wiki post about [Liferay Plugins-SDK](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugins+SDK) you can get started with creating your own portlet (if you haven't done so already).

Hope this helps!